# Качественные предикторы в задачах классификации

Tags: python, r, статистика, машинное-обучение

Есть задача бинарной классификации. И есть мн-во предикторов, в том числе качественные. Применяю алгоритмы дерева решений, логит-модель и SVM с линейным ядром.Вопрос такой, нужно ли для каждого из этих алгоритмов создавать индикаторные переменные для качественных, то есть исключать один уровень из рассмотрения? Знаю что в задаче **клммр** нужно, иначе матрицу не обратить. Но как поступить тут?
Например, оценивая **логит-модель** по всем переменным в **sklearn** я получаю коэффициенты для каждого из уровней качественных переменных, а оценивая в **R**, для каждой из качественных переменной в уравнении он убирает по уровню.

Comment: Нужны примеры кода. Пока что похоже, что с использованием sklearn делаете что-то неправильно. В R при построении модели либо будет выполнено преобразование в индикаторные "на лету", либо будут использованы оригинальные категориальные переменные (когда это возможно). Для тех же деревьев можно использовать индикаторы и один уровень не убирать.

Comment: В R есть понятие «базовый уровень», с которым сравниваются значения зависимой переменной для всех остальных уровней. Этот базовый уровень в summary не отражается.